# How to swap items with CSS grids?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm in a grid display and i need to move tiles to change the order of the numbers
The grid is a 4x4 grid, and all the tiles have the same dimension

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tiles-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container{
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}

.tiles-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "1 2 3 4"
    "5 6 7 8"
    "9 10 11 12"
    "13 14 15 0";
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}




.tiles-container > div:nth-child(1){grid-area: 10;} /* the number 1 needs to go to the 10 in the grid-template-areas above*/
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(2){grid-area: 2;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(3){grid-area: 14;} 
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(4){grid-area: 7;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(5){grid-area: 8;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(6){grid-area: 4;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(7){grid-area: 3;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(8){grid-area: 11;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(9){grid-area: 15;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(10){grid-area: 13;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(11){grid-area: 0;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(12){grid-area: 12;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(13){grid-area: 6;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(14){grid-area: 5;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(15){grid-area: 9;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(16){grid-area: 1;}
```

But when i check the result, the grid is totally messed up and is showing a lot of rows

And also i would like to know if we can make somehow a transition of two items swapping

Thanks

Comment: either by the use of `order` or `grid-area`

Comment: don't use number to name your areas

Answer (score 1):

The big issue I think you're having here is that `grid-area` is not one number for placement, it is two numbers like `1/2` for row 1 column 2.

I assumed when you say `grid-area: 1` you mean Row 1, Column 1. And when you say 14 you mean row 4, column 2. I took the liberty of replacing all the `grid-area` values, and writing a bit of js that can handle swapping two grid items.

hopefully this helps you with your efforts!

```js
(() => {
  const $ = str => [...document.querySelectorAll(str)];
  let active = undefined;
  function tileClicked(e) {
    const el = e.target;
    if (active == el) return;
    if (active == undefined) {
      active = el;
      el.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      const elStyles = getComputedStyle(el);
      const elGridArea = elStyles.getPropertyValue(
        "grid-area"
      );
      const activeStyles = getComputedStyle(active);
      const activeGridArea = activeStyles.getPropertyValue(
        "grid-area"
      );
      
      el.style.gridArea = activeGridArea;
      active.style.gridArea = elGridArea;
      
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active = undefined;
    }
  }
  $(".tiles-container div").forEach(tile => {
    tile.addEventListener("click", tileClicked);
  });
})();
```

```css
.container{
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}

.tiles-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "1 2 3 4"
    "5 6 7 8"
    "9 10 11 12"
    "13 14 15 0";
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.tiles-container > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tiles-container > div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 255);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(210, 210, 255);
}


.tiles-container > div:nth-child(1){grid-area: 3/2;} /* the number 1 needs to go to the 10 in the grid-template-areas above*/
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(2){grid-area: 1/2;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(3){grid-area: 4/2;} 
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(4){grid-area: 2/3;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(5){grid-area: 2/4;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(6){grid-area: 1/4;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(7){grid-area: 1/3;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(8){grid-area: 3/3;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(9){grid-area: 4/3;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(10){grid-area: 4/1;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(11){grid-area: 4/4;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(12){grid-area: 3/4;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(13){grid-area: 2/2;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(14){grid-area: 2/1;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(15){grid-area: 3/1;}
.tiles-container > div:nth-child(16){grid-area: 1/1;}
```

```html
Click 2 swap!
<div class="container">
  <div class="tiles-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```